# What's the semantical difference between the two statements?

Tags: java, interface, casting, static, this

I have two (pretty useless) `interfaces` with `test1` extending `test`

```
interface test
{
    int a = 8;
    void show();
}

interface test1 extends test
{
    int a = 4;
    void show();
}
```

I have a class `MyClass` (again a bit useless) implementing the `test1` interface

```
public class MyClass implements test1
{
    public void show()
    {
       System.out.println(((test)this).a);    // 1
       System.out.println(test.a);            // 2
    }
    public static void main(String ar[])
    {
        new MyClass().show();
    }
}
```

Out of the code I've provided, I'm interested in knowing what is the *semantical difference*(if any) between the two statements ordered as **1.** and **2.** respectively; Because result wise, correct me if I'm wrong they're pretty much the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference. But it's not a good practice to refer to static members through an instance reference.

Casting `this` to a parent to access its static field is *really* misleading.

Answer (score 2):

So, interface variables are by default `public static final`. **There is no difference between `((test)this).a` and `test.a`** as for `((test)this)` compiler expect a reference type of `test`. For compiler **this** really does not matter. For example

```
System.out.println(((test)null).a);
```

The above line also work and gives you proper output.